# Fresh load of 19.10, no arrow pointer

Tags: 19.10

Loading 19.10 from a USB memory stick on a new PC goes well, no observed error messages, but there is no pointer arrow.  If I'm very careful, I can move the mouse around and can highlight and click icons.

Any suggestions how to get the arrow to appear?

Comment: "PC" => not "laptop" - pull the mouse cord (USB?) plug, wait a few seconds and re-insert it - if that doesn't help; you need to provide give more detail.

Comment: Yes, PC, not laptop.  Yes, USB mouse.  Unplugged/Re-plugged and no change.

What details can I provide to help?  Its a pretty ordinary box.  It is odd to me that moving the mouse around does highlight icons and clicking will select, there's just no arrow so you have to be real lucky to hover in the right spot

Comment: LarryM, it's not supposed to work that way, you should see the mouse cursor. Did you check the ISO file you used to make your installation LiveUSB by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 .? Might have been a glitch during download. If it did verify, reboot from the LiveUSB and tell us if you see the mouse pointer when you choose _Try Ubuntu Without Installing_.

Comment: "LarryM, it's not supposed to work that way, you should see the mouse cursor" - well, ya, but it doesn't.  The box did this when my step-son loaded it up on a version he downloaded, and it does it exactly the same on the version I downloaded (which successfully loaded a different box) - so I don't think its a problem with the image.

The box did the same thing when booting from the USB.  So that's two different USB sticks, with two downloads of 19.10 on them, both right off the USB and after loading the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lightdm then this may work `sudo service lightdm restart` 
Or you can shift from  lightdm to gdm:`sudo apt-get install gdm`

Comment: This is a straight out of the box install since I can't steer it to anything after loading.  Don't know what lightdm is, but entering the first command gets: Failed to lightdm.service: unit lightdm.service not found

Entering the second command gets: E: Package 'gdm' has no installation candidate